# Best practice for handling secondary page requests

Tags: facebook, authorization, facebook-c#-sdk

When building a Facebook tab application the first page receives the signed request, my question is what is the best practice to handle the secondary requests.  You could save the related information in a cookie to have it on the secondary requests but that seems a little unsecured to me.

I am just curious what is the recommend way to handle this basic situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signed request is just an intermediate step to getting the access_token and userid.

I put the access token into Session, and I also encrypt it and save it in a cookie.  Facebook app development has taught me to go belt-and-suspenders when it comes to authentication.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was thinking but just wanted some outside validation.